# Airflow Webserver worker not launching

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-webserver

I am new to Airflow so please pardon me if it is a stupid doubt. My workspace in a server which was hosting Airflow had crashed and I was trying to restart it , but all my attempts have been in vain so far, I am stuck with below message in airflow scheduler

```
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:53158)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:53159)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:53160)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:53161)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [53158] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 53158)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [53161] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 53161)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [53160] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 53160)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [53159] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 53159)
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [54227] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54227
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 53161 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 53158 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 53160 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [54228] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54228
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [54229] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54229
[2021-11-22 13:17:07 +0000] [54230] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54230
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:54227)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:54228)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:54229)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:54230)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [54227] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 54227)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [54229] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 54229)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [54228] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 54228)
[2021-11-22 13:19:07 +0000] [54230] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 54230)
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [55302] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55302
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 54228 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 54230 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 54229 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [55303] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55303
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [55304] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55304
[2021-11-22 13:19:08 +0000] [55307] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55307
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:55302)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:55303)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:55304)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:55307)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [55304] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55304)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [55307] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55307)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [55303] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55303)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [55302] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55302)
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [56379] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56379
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 55307 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 55303 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [56380] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56380
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [56381] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56381
[2021-11-22 13:21:08 +0000] [56382] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56382
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:56379)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:56380)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:56381)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:56382)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [56382] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56382)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [56380] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56380)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [56379] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56379)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [56381] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56381)
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [57440] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 57440
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 56381 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 56380 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [49852] [WARNING] Worker with pid 56379 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [57441] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 57441
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [57448] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 57448
[2021-11-22 13:23:09 +0000] [57449] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 57449
```

My scheduler is running in another terminal and has below status , I have killed and restarted my job countless time now and am at my wits end

```
[2021-11-22 13:12:37,178] {manager.py:532} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2 ) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1.
[2021-11-22 13:12:37,449] {scheduler_job.py:1239} INFO - Marked 1 SchedulerJob instances as failed
[2021-11-22 13:17:41,660] {scheduler_job.py:1217} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2021-11-22 13:22:46,052] {scheduler_job.py:1217} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
```